# XAMPP regressing of PHP and Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, php, xampp

In the documentation for XAMPP there is a HOW-TO on how to use older versions of PHP using XAMPP. In the first step it states the following :

> Download a binary build of the PHP version that you wish to use from
>   the PHP website, and extract the contents of the compressed archive
>   file to your XAMPP installation directory (usually, C:\xampp). Ensure
>   that you give it a different directory name to avoid overwriting the
>   existing PHP version. For example, in this tutorial, we’ll call the
>   new directory C:\xampp\php5-6-0.
>
> Ensure that the PHP build you download matches the Apache build (VC9
>   or VC11) in your XAMPP platform.

The part I'm concerned about is the matching version of Apache. there is no resource I can find on how to install older versions of Apache to match the PHP version. Does this not really matter or should I just install the older PHP version which in my case uses VC11 and it should word with VC15.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to *acquire* a copy of either `php`, or `apache`. First look at what *versions* of it, it's *compatible* with. Best direction; decide which version of `Apache` you want to run. Download, install it, then do the same for `PHP`. It's not difficult to do. Simply going to the associated web sites, and looking for (minimum) requirements should do it. For example; Requires: `Apache >= 2.2`. They're pretty good at indicating that sort of thing. Try the downloads section(s). Find one you'd like to run. Then find "requirements".

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've done this and found the version of PHP and Apache to use but I'm getting a server error when trying to use them with XAMPP. I've added the extension modules similar to how they were used in version of PHP that came with the current install of XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no resource I can find on how to install older versions of Apache to match the PHP version.

XAMMP is essentially a front-end to what are normally separate programs. So Apache can (technically) be swapped out in a similar fashion to PHP. That is, you can download e.g. [Apache 2.4.38 built with VC11](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/) and use it in place of Apache 2.4.39 built with VC15 (which is the current default for XAMMP).

**Caveats**

The process with Apache isn't quite "drag and drop". You will need to copy over some files and folders from your original XAMMP Apache installation (those that don't otherwise exist in the version of Apache you downloaded).

In the main `apache` directory, these include:

- The `scripts` folder.
- `apache_installservice.bat`
- `apache_uninstallinstallservice.bat`
- `makecert.bat`

Pay attention to the `conf` folder as well. It holds the actual configuration for Apache, as well as some extra files for XAMMP specifically. Apache 2.4.38 and Apache 2.4.39 should be close enough that you can (likely) replace the entire `conf` folder in your downloaded version of Apache with XAMMP's version.

When installing your older version of PHP, you will also need to update `XAMMP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` to make the proper references to PHP 5 rather than PHP 7 (there are about 3 lines to update):

*ex. httpd-xampp.conf (Partial)*

```
# LoadFile "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/php7ts.dll"
# LoadFile "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/libpq.dll"
# LoadModule php7_module "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

LoadFile "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

[...]

# <IfModule php7_module>
<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/Programs/XAMMP/php"
</IfModule>
```

Note that Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP are intended for IIS. Thread Safe (TS) versions are intended for Apache and are the only distributions to include e.g. `php5ts.dll` and `php5apache2_4.dll`.

One suggestion I would make for both PHP and Apache is that you keep the original XAMMP versions (i.e. simply rename the folders), at least until you can confirm that everything is working the way you want it to.

Be aware that if you have Apache installed as a service, you will likely need to stop the service (as necessary), then uninstall/reinstall the service via the XAMMP interface.

---

*There may also be additional steps I haven't covered here to get things working properly, depending on your installation.*

---

> Does this really matter or should I just install the older PHP version (which in my case uses VC11) and it should work with VC15?

Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, Apache 2.4.39 built with VC15 (VC15 being the important part) will not work with PHP built under VC11 (though it may work with any version of PHP built under VC14).

One remedy to this in the past was to use `mod_fcgid`, rather than running PHP as a module directly. However,  I believe current versions of `mod_fgcid` no longer work with PHP 5.5 (though more recent versions may work with PHP 5.6+).

Comment: So I tried what you suggested but I'm still having trouble getting Apache to start with the older version of PHP and Apache. The PHP version I grabbed was not thread safe version and php5appache2_4.dll wasn't inlcuded in the installation. On other forums there is a lot of information that I'm not following, such as using only thread safe versions of the PHP and Apache version, but the 5.5.9 version I'm trying to use for this doesn't seem to have a thread safe version.

Comment: Correction, I just realized there is a Thread Safe PHP version.

Comment: Just to confirm, Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP are intended for IIS. Thread Safe (TS) versions are intended for Apache and are the only distribution to include `php5apache2_4.dll`, etc.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I'm still having trouble with using the older version of PHP. I've tried modifying the php.ini file to be closer to the original PHP that was installed in XAMPP but I'm continuously getting the following error.

This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying

Not sure if this is an Apache or a PHP problem.

Comment: It could be a variety of things (PHP or Apache). I believe that the most common is the PHP code generating fatal errors (perhaps due to syntax issues). Other common issues likely include your code timing out if making external requests (databases, URLs, etc). Line endings (LF vs CRLF) can be another issue. Permission issues generally or specific .htaccess issues can be another problem. I would try at least running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a `.php` file. If it returns information about PHP successfully, then the problem likely shouldn't be with the Apache/PHP interface.

Comment: Checking logs is always a good idea, too.

Comment: I would also add that any CGI scripts typically have very specific needs in what they initially return. Before you write the document body, you typically need `Content-type: text/plain` or `Content-type: text/html` and two or more blank lines for CGI scripts. This probably doesn't apply to any PHP script your running, but it is one other thing that can cause a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: So the logs for PHP don't exist. That was something I should have mentioned. I did find that PHPMyADMIN is innaccessible in XAMPP. I went as far as reinstalling XAMPP twice cleanly and PHPMYADMIN is still not working. "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information." So I'm not sure what to do, it looks like something isn't being uninstalled when I reinstall XAMPP because this problem still persists despite a fresh install.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fully and totally just reinstall XAMPP, Windows 10 is messing it up somehow.